# How to convert the varchar data type in date through query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table in database in oracle where the  field `TIMESTAMP_MAIN` is of `VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)` ..

```
TIMESTAMP_MAIN
2016-11-23T14:58:22
```

How do i convert the column to the date in the given format. I am trying the below query:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP_MAIN, 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss') from ACCOUNT;
```

It is giving the following error:

**ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:

*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 44**

what could be the reason for the error..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to handle the `T` with double quotes and to fix `MM` into `MI` for minutes:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP_MAIN, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') from ACCOUNT;
```

I also edited `HH` into `HH24`, given that in your example you have hours written in 24H format

Comment: @dhs - Pay attention to what Aleksej says here - fix the T but ALSO fix the minutes format:  you have MM which means "month" not "minutes" and you'll get the wrong result if you don't fix this. Common mistake (I made it many times!)

Comment: @mathguy : I only noticed it because, without fixing it, it gave me "ORA-01810: format code appears twice" :)